# Rotation broken in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, orientation

I've been trying all morning to fix this, to no avail. Here's my situation:

I have a navigation controller across two views in my app. The first view shouldn't rotate away from portrait. The second view should rotate between portrait and landscape. Going back to the first view should send it back to portrait.

Here's the code I have currently (which i've experimented with without success, so is in no way solid):

AppDelegate:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application
supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Navigation controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}
```

First view controller:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Second view controller:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

The current behaviour is that app will stay in portait on the first VC, rotate properly on the second VC, but if I go back while in landscape, the first VC is in landscape and stays there. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think that type of interface rotation is discouraged and is not easily supported under iOS 6+. UINavigationController is documented as "Do not subclass". You'll have more luck if you present your second view controller as a modal view instead of via the navigation controller. Modally presented view controllers can rotate independently of their presenting view controller.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, and as far as I can remember, you can't fix it due to the way how auto-rotation works. However, I did come up with a workaround - when in landscape mode, I hid the navigation bar, disabling the option to tap the back button. This might or might not work for you, but if you come up with a better solution, I would love to hear it.